# black space below tabbar on iphone 5

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6, iphone-5

I'm currently developing a new app. This app has a login screen. When you login. You go to a tabbar controller. But below my tabbar there is a black space. You can see it below here. Anybody has an idea how to get this right?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is normal, your app does not support the 4" screen size. To make sure that apps do not break apple will run apps that do not support the 4" screen in 3.5" mode.

To get your app to support the 4" Screen size add new start screen with the name `Default-568h@2x.png` with the dimension of 640x1136

Answer (score 1):

Add Splash image of dimension 640x1136 with name Default-568h@2x.png and check again..